# Creating new class versions

Tags: java, version

I'm currently working on a project. I've been running into a few issues with the e-mail functionality, I've made multiple attempts to fix the issue and the latest seems to have fixed the issue.

For each rewrite I've created a new class to hold the new code. This doesn't seem to be the best solution as each time I have to go through the code and track down the references to the class and update them, with each rewrite only the code for the actual sending of the email has changed, function inputs and names have been consistent.

I've looked up versioning but this hasn't been particularly helpful in providing a solution either granted most likely due to my own lack of knowledge on the subject. So here is what I'm looking for: to have one instance of the class with multiple versions preferably without all the old code in it to aid in reading. But I want access to the old versions so that if a function/feature was there previously and wasn't built into the current version I can see how it was implemented.

Comment: The thing is, any solution without version control is basically going to mimic it, so you might as well just learn it. If you can't understand something about versioning, you could always just ask for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Versioning is *exactly* what you need here.

Have a look [here](http://www.scribd.com/doc/2301648/Subversion-Overview), which gives you a brief introduction to subversion, one of the most popular versioning systems. You can either set up / use your own private subversion server, or if you project is open source use a number of free providers (such as Google code) who will provide versioning for you.

Other versioning systems exist other than subversion, such as git, mercurial, etc. - but subversion is arguably the most popular and a good starting point.

Comment: +1 for suggesting subversion. IMO, it is one of the easiest to learn for beginners.

Comment: After switching away from SVN, I can't imagine *ever* willingly going back to it .. Hg is my current preference because "it's simple enough for me to use well". (SVN merging is .. a nightmare. "Tree conflicts" anyone? They were the last straw for me.)

Comment: @Sujay I actually believe Hg is *much simpler* to learn than SVN. TortoiseHg workbench is simpler/unified than TortoiseSVN and it is a more streamlined flow, IMOHO. After using SVN for a few years, I *still* don't really understand which way to merge, and why .. on the other hand, I can get someone *productive* on Hg in half a day.

Comment: @pst well, i agree! sometimes SVN can be a nightmare...however its mostly a matter of preference, or your project requirement. in my experience i've gotten to use many such version control mechanism and well, all of them have their fair share of advantages/disadvantages :)

Comment: It's all preference - I picked SVN for this post purely because from a beginner's perspective it's the most widely used and the most supported. Pretty much everyone using something else other than SVN *was* using it and moved away from it, and to that end I'd say even if the OP does move away from it, having experience with SVN is still a very useful skill to have, and will be for a long time yet. Regardless, the main point in this post is that he needs versioning of some form, whatever system is chosen.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using any IDE? Eclipse/Netbeans store the history of your file updates and you can always compare/replace from history.

**Note:** This is not a replacement of version control in any way and I would *highly recommend* that you explore open-source version control solutions. This would help you in the long run

Answer (score 0):

Mercurial is the way to go. Seemless merging and integration with java and popular IDE's like Netbeans. You can't go wrong. From the very beginning of my programming experience I learned how to use Mercurial in a day.

Answer (score 0):

Use version management tool likes as SVN or CVS.